# iptables: packet counter behavior for MASQUERADE rule

Tags: counter, iptables, packet

I noticed a "strange" behavior of the packet counter for `POSTROUTING` chain (`MASQUERADE` rule) in my "router" (`CentOS` 7), that when I `ping` the outside from 
 the NATed LAN, the `pkts` fields does not increase as many as the ping requests I sent.

For example, if I send 10 `ICMP` echo requests using `ping <dest-ip> -c 10`, the `pkts` field in `POSTROUTING` chain only increase by 1. If I ping one packet by one packet (i.e., issue multiple `ping -c 1 <dest-ip>` commands), the `pkts` field usually increases as expected (if the time gap between consecutive ping command is longer enough).

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 50 packets, 3302 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      63     4696 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    172.16.1.0/24        0.0.0.0/0
```

For the same ping test, I watched the `pkts` field in both `PREROUTING` and `FORWARD` chain. The counter behavior is the same for `PREROUTING` and `POSTROUTING` chains, but the `FORWARD` chain has a "normal" behavior that the counter will increase exactly as the number of ICMP packets I sent.

Using Wireshark to capture ICMP packages at both client and the "router", it shows that the ICMP request/reply communication matches the ping command.

I guess I missed some knowledge about this particular packet counter behavior...can you please indicate the source of information on this?

Thanks a lot.